# Salesforce Document Unique Name Issue

Tags: document, recycle-bin

We are facing an issue with "Salesforce Document" while uploading a document in "My Personal Document".

After uploading a "Test Document" if we delete it, we are not able to upload a "Test Document" with the same name as deleted file. It shows below error message :
"This Document Unique Name already exists or has been previously used. Please choose a different name."

We deleted that document from recycle bin as well.
Is it the behavior of Salesforce Document or a bug?

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's standard behavior. Records in recycle bin are a result of a soft delete, thus they tend to keep intact the api names or unique names with them until they are hard deleted or deleted from recycle bin.

Also, you may want to vote this Idea up:
[Allow re-use of Report Unique Name](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZKibAAG)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this. We are getting this error after deleting from Recycle Bin. Specifically this issue for "Documents".

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well.. Anybody got a solution or a workaround?